# How to take databse dump of ABC database of table XYZ and only of organization_id "22"?

Tags: mysql, database

Lets Say I have database named ABC.
And tables X,Y,Z,M,N which has organization_id 0-50.
How is it possible to create a dump file for tables X,Y,Z with only organization_id=22 ?

Comment: You can use the mysqldump utility to dump one table at a time filtering it with the `--where` option. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go through table by table and do

```
mysqldump -uroot -p db_name table_name --where='id=22'
```

or you can use

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'data_path.sql' from table where id=22
```

Answer (score 0):

using mysqldump tool you can do that , as you mentioned your database is ABC , and tables are X,Y,Z.hope this works for you.

```
mysqldump -u db_user -p ABC X Y Z --no_create_info  \  
--lock-all-tables --where 'organization_id  \
in (SELECT X.organization_id FROM X  \
    JOIN Y  ON X.organization_id = Y.organization_id  \
    JOIN Z  ON Y.organization_id = Z.organization_id   \
    WHERE X.organization_id = 22)' > data.sql
```

Comment: I am curious, does this export all tables with this where? Cause this looks like it would just output one datatable with all data joined together instead of backing up all tables with only the data where

Comment: @veritaS: Thanks,This one might does. Updated.

Comment: Thankyou @Humayoun_Kabir For the answer. Will the answer help if i have to   insert the data of organization_id=22 in same table but in another organization_id=5 from same data.sql file by replacing ,22, to ,5, ????